# Errors on parameters using scipy.curve_fit

Tags: optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am fitting the following function (variables A, D, μ and τ) and x and E are fixed:
[image]

I created some example data using the equation and added some noise. The fit looks very good and has a low chi-squared however the errors from the covariance matrix are odd; some are very large whereas others are smaller. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Constants
E_field = 1
x = 1

def function(t, A, D, μ, τ):
  return A/np.sqrt(4*np.pi*D*t) * np.exp(-pow(x-μ*E_field*t, 2)/(4*D*t) - t/τ)

def chi(E, O):
  return np.sum(np.ma.masked_invalid(pow(O-E, 2)/E))

def fit(t, n, m, p0):
  ddof = n.size - m
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(function, t, n, p0=p0)
  fitted_n = function(t, *popt)
  reduced_χ_squared = chi(n, fitted_n) / ddof
  σ = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
  return popt, σ, reduced_χ_squared

# Choose random variables to generate data
x, t = 1, np.linspace(0.01, 5, num=100)
A, D, μ, τ = 1, 0.2, 1, 1
n = function(t, A, D, μ, τ)

n_noise = n + 0.005 * np.random.normal(size=n.size)
n_noise += abs(min(n_noise)) # Shift data to lie on y = 0

p0 = [1, 0.25, 1, 1]
vars, σ, reduced_χ_squared = fit(t, n_noise, 4, p0)
fitted_A, fitted_D, fitted_μ, fitted_τ = vars
σ_A, σ_D, σ_μ, σ_τ = σ
fitted_n = function(t, *vars)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, n_noise)
ax.plot(t, fitted_n)
#ax.text(0.82, 0.75, "χᵣ²={:.4f}".format(reduced_χ_squared), transform = ax.transAxes)
ax.legend(["Observed n", "Expected n"])
print("Fitted parameters: A = {:.4f}, D = {:.4f}, μ = {:.4f}, τ = {:.4f}".format(*vars))
print("Fitted parameter errors: σ_A = {:.4f}, σ_D = {:.4f}, σ_μ = {:.4f}, σ_τ = {:.4f}".format(*σ))
print("Reduced χ² = {:.4f}".format(reduced_χ_squared))
```

Running this code gives me the following output
[image: Fitted function overlayed on "observed" data]

Comment: I do not think those are meaningful for a non-parametric curve fit. I would not pay attention to them. The quality of fit looks fine.

Comment: @piterbarg Thanks for the info. Do you know how I would be able to calculate the errors on the fitted parameters?

Comment: I would do a bunch of fits using different random numbers for each fit (ie do not fix your seed for your `random` calls) and calculate standard deviations of fitted parameters from that. Frankly however I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish with calculating those errors.

Comment: @piterbarg I am using this in a lab experiment but just wanted to test the scipy.curve_fit would work well for this equation. Do you mean the seed for the noise? In that case I won't be able to do that with real data

Comment: A few thoughts. One, the fit seems to work well for your synthetic data. As long as you real data is similar to your synthetic data, it should work ok. If it is not, then there are no guarantees obviously. Two, yes I do mean by using different seeds. yes that will only tell you the errors on your parameters for your synthetic data. Again if you real data is similar, you should get some comfort from this experiment. if not, you won't. But then these calculations from curve_fit will not tell you more (in fact I am not sure they tell you anything at all) that the experiment I suggest.

Comment: @piterbarg Thanks for the help. Just one final question you could help me with. If I provide the explicit Jacobian does that have the potential to fix the errors? I recall that the errors are derived from a numerical approximation of the Jacobian

Comment: I very much doubt it. Also to be clear I do not see these as errors but as meaningless, in this context, calculations

Comment: This happens if you only look at the diagonal elements of your covariance matrix.  The parameters are highly correlated. In some cases it can be helpful to introduce a transformation to remove this and make numerics a bit more trustworthy, but at the end it is inherent to the problem at hand. Actually, in a not very stable case like this you might profit from giving the Jacobian explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above, correlation is a big problem here. Biggest problem though is that you fit more parameters than required.

Let us transform:

```py
A = exp( alpha) i.e alpha = log(A)
delta = 4 * D
epsilon = mu * E
```

We then get:

```py
1 / sqrt( pi* delta ) *  exp( -( x**2 + epsilon**2 * t**2 -2*x*epsilon t) / ( delta * t ) -t / tau + alpha )

= 1 / sqrt( pi* delta ) * exp( -( x**2 + epsilon**2 * t**2 -2*x*epsilon t) / ( delta * t ) -delta / tau * t**2/( delta * t) + delta * alpha * t/ ( delta * t ) )

= 1 / sqrt( pi* delta ) * exp( -( x**2 + epsilon**2 * t**2 -2*x*epsilon t + delta / tau * t**2 - delta * alpha * t ) / ( delta * t ) )

= 1 / sqrt( pi* delta ) * exp( -( x**2 + ( epsilon**2 + delta / tau ) * t**2 -x * ( 2 * epsilon + delta * alpha ) * t ) / ( delta * t ) )
```

now renaming:

```py
( epsilon**2 + delta / tau ) -> gamma**2

( 2 * epsilon + delta * alpha ) -> eta
```

we get

```py
= 1 / sqrt( pi * delta ) * exp( -( x**2 + gamma**2 * t**2 - x * eta * t ) / ( delta * t ) )
```

So there are actually only 3 parameters to fit and it looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Constants
E_field = 1
x = 1

def function(t, A, D, μ, τ):
  return A/np.sqrt(4*np.pi*D*t) * np.exp(-pow(x-μ*E_field*t, 2)/(4*D*t) - t/τ)

def alt_func( t, gamma, eta, delta ):
    return np.exp( -( x**2 + gamma**2 * t**2 - eta * t ) / ( delta * t ) ) / np.sqrt( np.pi * delta * t )


# Choose random variables to generate data
x, t = 1, np.linspace(0.01, 5, num=100)
A, D, μ, τ = 1, 0.2, 1, 1
n = function(t, A, D, μ, τ)

n_noise = n + 0.005 * np.random.normal(size=n.size)
n_noise += abs(min(n_noise)) # Shift data to lie on y = 0

guess=[1.34, 2, .8]
palt, covalt = curve_fit( alt_func, t, n_noise)
print( covalt )
print( palt )
yt = alt_func( t, *palt )
yg = alt_func( t, *guess )
yorg = function( t, A, D, μ, τ )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, n_noise)
ax.plot(t, yg )
ax.plot(t, yt, ls="--")
ax.plot(t, yorg, ls=":" )
plt.show()
```

This has a reasonable covariance matrix. One can get the original parameters easily via error propagation.

**Altzernatively,** it should be enough to fix `A=1` and only fit the three left parameters in the original function.

Concerning the transformation and back calculation one has to keep in mind that this is of course from R³ to R⁴, so it is naturally not unique either. Again one can just fix one value, or one might to try to spread the error evenly between the parameters or who knows....

Comment: nice catch re: overfitting!